# How to Call a Python Project from another Python project

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, tkinter, pycharm

I am not a programmer, so please bear with me if I'm inaccurate or don't really understand the replies.

I use PyCharm , it works really well for me, python scripts are called projects in PyCharm and I am running a couple of webscraping scripts to retrieve competitor prices on the internet.  They are quite simple but work rather well.  In order to go through the process I have to call every script (one for every competitor) independently, wait for it to finish, then I call the other one, etc.  I could actually call or run all them simultaneously but it gets visually very messy, there are errors sometimes and it's just simpler to run one at a time, and get the results, they take 10-15 minutes each tops.

But I can't just sit around to wait for them to finish.  I tried merging them into one large project but that was really messy, as every webpage has nuances, differences, I use different variables for every page to allow for differences, it's just simpler this way.  But it is time consuming and basically forces me to stay put while running them.

I am trying to automate the process and am using TkInter to write a small project that would (ideally) call or run each one, one at a time, and I also hope to retrieve an exit code as well from every project that runs, in order for me to know if the project/script ran properly or not.

I have TkInter semi sorted out and have managed to get buttons, a clock, etc up and running (I am planning on running this script four times a day, every 3 hours approximately).  I am confident I can do the GUI TkInter bit.

But I have been unable to call / run / import a PyCharm project from another PyCharm project.  Here's the last iteration of what I have been trying out and using (these are called when pressing a button on the TkInter GUI:

```
  # create button, link it to run web price scraper program
    webscraperbutton = Button(self, text="Run", command=self.run_price_scraper)
    # place button at (400,100)
    webscraperbutton.place(x=200, y=100)

def run_price_scraper(self):
    # exec(open('/Users/manuel/PycharmProjects/PriceScraper/main.py').read())
    # os.system("/Users/manuel/PycharmProjects/PriceScraper/main.py")
    # subprocess.call('/Users/manuel/PycharmProjects/PriceScraper/main.py', shell=True)
```

They are all #d as I have been trying various combinations but nothing works so far.

Here are the errors I get:

```
subprocess.call('/Users/manuel/PycharmProjects/PriceScraper/main.py', shell=True)

 from: can't read /var/mail/selenium
 from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.webdriver.chrome.options
 from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.webdriver.support.select
 from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.webdriver.common.by
 from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.webdriver.support.ui
 from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.webdriver.support
 /Users/manuel/PycharmProjects/PriceScraper/main.py: line 8: import: command not found
 /Users/manuel/PycharmProjects/PriceScraper/main.py: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `('
 /Users/manuel/PycharmProjects/PriceScraper/main.py: line 12: `chrome_options = Options()'
From os.system("/Users/manuel/PycharmProjects/PriceScraper/main.py") same error

from: can't read /var/mail/selenium
from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.webdriver.chrome.options
from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.webdriver.support.select
from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.webdriver.common.by
from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.webdriver.support.ui
from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.webdriver.support
/Users/manuel/PycharmProjects/PriceScraper/main.py: line 8: import: command not found
/Users/manuel/PycharmProjects/PriceScraper/main.py: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Users/manuel/PycharmProjects/PriceScraper/main.py: line 12: `chrome_options = Options()'


From exec(open('/Users/manuel/PycharmProjects/PriceScraper/main.py').read())

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 
1884, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "/Users/manuel/PycharmProjects/PYGUI/main.py", line 31, in run_stock_scraper
exec(open('/Users/manuel/PycharmProjects/PriceScraper/main.py').read())
File "<string>", line 402, in <module>
File "<string>", line 29, in site_login
NameError: name 'driver' is not defined
```

How can I, in a simple way, just call or run another PyCharm project, let it run through and get an exit code?

I have thought of trying to make a Python app out of every project / script, and try calling an app instead, but I have no idea if that is even doable.

Here are the lines

```
# Import Libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import pandas as pd


# Start the session
chrome_options = Options()

# Option to run Headless
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

# Activate Chrome Selenium Driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Applications/System Utilities/chromedriver')
# Define maximum wait
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
```

these are the next few lines i edited some things for obvious reasons but like I said before this all works flawlessly

```
# Site Login Function
def site_login():
    # Login Data
    username = "XXXXXXXXXX"
    password = "XXXXXXXXXX"

    driver.get('https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.com/')
    # Wait for element to be present
    wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "okta-signin-username")))
    # Send Username
    driver.find_element_by_id("okta-signin-username").send_keys(username)
    # print("username")
    # Wait for element to be present
    wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "okta-signin-password")))
    # Send Password
    driver.find_element_by_id("okta-signin-password").send_keys(password)
    # print("password")
    # Wait for element to be present
    wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "okta-signin-submit")))
    # Click Signin
    driver.find_element_by_id("okta-signin-submit").click()
    # print("Click")
```

Comment: Creating separate projects just for several simple scripts does not sound good. Try running each script in a loop or you might want to look for a structured approach.

Comment: From the look of the errors the problems are in the scripts themselves, not in how you are calling them

Comment: But they work perfectly when called independently

Comment: I am probably completely wrong, but I have a feeling that it has to do more with how pycharm sets up the environments than how i am calling them, it would seem to me that it does not know how to run a script or project that runs fine when called on its own.   I also tried looking into the interpreter etc but everything looked fine.   Probably wrong though !!!

Comment: Please edit the question to include the first 12 or so lines of PriceScraper/main.py, that might give me a clue as to what the problem is

Comment: The first few lines are now in the question

Comment: `File "<string>", line 29, in site_login  NameError: name 'driver' is not defined` suggests that there's a problem with function site_login on line 29. Could you show that part of code?

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 0):

As for the subprocesses, have you tried to define explicitly that the files should be launched by python, like `subprocess.run(['python3', '/Users/manuel/PycharmProjects/PriceScraper/main.py'], shell=True)`?

Reference for library subprocess: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Some examples: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/50/subprocess.Popen
and https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/50/subprocess.run

Comment: no I have not will try it next thanks, that actually sounds like it could work, I think pycharm is what is preventing me from calling other projects, I am stuck on blaming pycharm, anyway will report on how tat goes, well I just did and  i got the beach ball thingy on macos, BTW I am working on Big Sur, if it makes any difference.  I will let it "think" for a while, but at least it did not crash, it is stuck

Comment: To prevent 'beach ball' on time-consuming tasks, you may want to use subprocess.Popen in place of subprocess.run: subprocess.run is synchronous/blocking, while subprocess.Popen is asynchronous/non-blocking. Please check the links mentioned previously for more details. To get a response from a subprocess (e.g., to start another subprocess subsequently), you should be able to inject events to your main event loop / root window using [event generate](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/event.htm#M7). I'm also on Big Sur, using PySimpleGUI wrapper for tkinter.